# Order of elements in groups

Tags: group-theory

In order to find the order of any element $g \in G$ with respect to any subgroup $H$, is the order basically $|G/H|$?

Comment: Probably you need to define $H_j$ first!

Comment: So $H=H_{j-1}$...? Is your group $G$ Abelian in the first place?

Comment: Yup, H=$H_{j-1}$ and no it need not be abelian but the factor group $|H_j /H_{j−1}|$ is

Comment: It is not very useful to change your question into a rather different and less well defined question. The answer to the current question is much more evidently no than for the previous one: just taking $H=\{e\}$ you would be saying that the order of an element is just the order of the group, which is false even for Abelian groups except in rare situations, namely when $G$ is a cyclic group and $g$ generates the group. In your original question one could at least deduce for the case that is $G$ is Abelian then each $H_j/H_{j-1}$ is indeed a cyclic group with generator $g_j$, and so this holds.

Comment: Anonymous, why did you flag your own question as "off-topic"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false. $G=S_3$, $g_1=(1~2)$, $g_2=(2~3)$, $\#H_1=2$, $\#H_2=\#G=6$, $r_2=2\neq3=|H_2/H_1|$.

Comment: van     Ok im slightly confused, could you explain what does finding an order with respect to a subgroup mean, for example i have $Z_{12}$ and the normal chain $Z_{12} \geq Z_4=\{0,3,6,9\} \geq Z_2=\{0,6\} \geq \{0\}$, then if i want to find the order of element 5 with respect to subgroup $Z_4$ would it mean it has an order $|Z_{12}/Z_{4}|=3$? Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: If $H_j$ is an Abelian group, or more generally if $H_{j-1}$ is a normal subgroup of $H_j$, then the order of $g_j$ with respect to $H_{j-1}$ is just the order or the image of $g_j$ in the quotient group $H_j/H_{j-1}$, and this can be seen to be $r_j$. However in general $r_j$ is the order of the orbit of the coset $eH_{j-1}$ under the action of $g_j$, and this orbit may be smaller than all of $H_j/H_{j-1}$.